# Pushing binary DB data to heroku gets currupted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, taps

You can push your local DB to your Heroku app using the taps gem. The command is:

`heroku db:push`

This works fine for me except for when pushing binary data.

The data gets changed. For example here are the first few chars on my binary data locally: `\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x0` and here is it on heroku after being pushed: `x89504e470d0a1a0a000`

It seems like maybe the encoding gets lost, or the data gets unscaped.. I am not really sure.

<s>My local db is Sqlite3 and remote is Postgres, but it works for everything else.</s> I tried using Postgres locally and remotely.

I tried running with the --debug flag, but non of the output seemed to suggest any clues.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: i don't have an answer for you but... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development - "Using sqlite3 for development and PostgreSQL for Heroku - We strongly recommend against doing this"

Comment: @house9 Thanks for your suggestion, I tried changing my local DB to PG but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Is your local PG database good? Or you cannot get data into it from local sqlite?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, I created the local PG DB, inserted some fresh binary data, made sure it was stored correctly. Pushed to heroku, checked, it is not correct.

Comment: Try creating a local dump of your db and then restore that over your heroku db, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#importing-from-a-backup - assuming there is no production data you need to keep